# conda error - solving enviroment: failed with initial frozen solve.retrying with flexible solve

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I was trying to install packages from conda from the anaconda prompt and this error occurred every time (for different packages as well)
all I saw that some people said it is a problem in conda's current version , but for a friend of mine (who downloaded the exact same file) it worked well

Comment: Does it actually fail, or are you only concerned about that message? What you've shown is only an information message that Conda cannot install the requested package without changing the versions of some currently installed packages. Conda then proceeds to figure out how to optimally do that.

Comment: Also, what package are you trying to install? What exact command did you run that generated this message?

Comment: We're going to need far more information than this. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

I am a huge noob and therefore understand what OP doesn't understand:

Indeed, those messages don't tell you the actual error, just that conda can't currently figure out if it has the correct packages for the new installation. If you let it finish, THEN it will tell you what the actual errors are. I was confused as OP, thinking those messages were the actual errors. Once it can't install, it tells you what the package conflicts are. For example, mine has over 100 like this:

```
Package zlib conflicts for:
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']

wheel -> python -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']

cgal-cpp -> boost-cpp[version='>=1.72.0,<1.72.1.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']

sqlite -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
```

I've realized searching for those errors is how I will actually find the information to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it did not work. otherwise, I would not ask about it of course ... 
anyway I found that

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv 
conda install -c conda-forge gudhi
```

works, but you'll need to change your python interpreter to the one related to myenv

Answer (score 0):

I got the error on Windows 11 trying to install radian module. The following suggestion discovered by saar13531 works for me. Thanks for the posting.

conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install -c conda-forge radian

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33950623)